# Sharing calendars with EWS-API

Tags: exchangewebservices

I know how to [accept an invitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee693280(v=exchg.140).aspx) but I don't see how to share a calendar and invite someone to access it.

Can you please tell me which part of the API I need to use? API-Calls are made with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything in EWS that will allow you to create a Sharing request directly, you can use Protocol documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433485(v=exchg.80).aspx and build the sharing request email manually by setting all the necessary extended properties and creating the attachment eg one example is on http://willcode4foodblog.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/understanding-sharing-invitation-requests-ews-managed-api-1-2-part-1/

Cheers
Glen